# There was no end point listening at... error for wcf service

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller

I know there are lot of posts for this issue and I tried solutions from most of them but nothing seems to work.

I have a WCF service which was working fine in the Dev box when hosted on IIS and I moved this to the UAT box app server and I am able to access it and test if from the test client. So I now hosted my MVC application on the web server and from the web server browser I am able to access the service but when I run my web application which consumes the service it throws the following error.

```
Error Detail:- There was no endpoint listening at http://servername/AC.IS.BLService/CustService
.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect    
address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. 

Error TargetSite:- ACL.IS.BLWebSite.ViewModels.HomeAccountStatusViewModel  
ValidateLogin(ACL.IS.BLWebSite.ViewModels.HomeAccountStatusViewModel) 

Inner Exception:- System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an      
error: (404) Not Found. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at  

System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannel

Request.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

So,I tried hosting the service and the web application together on the same server and I still have the same problem. The following are my config files for both the service and client

**Client.config**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://servername/ACL.IS.BLService/CustService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustService"
    contract="BLService.ICustService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Server Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>      
  <service name="ACL.IS.BL_WebServices.CustService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="CustService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustService" contract="ACL.IS.BL_WebServices.ICustService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>    
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"  
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

its a windows 2012 server. IIS 8.5. Could somebody please help.

Just to mention..there is a firewall as well..does it have something to do with port numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server config says that it listens on port 8080:

```
baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"
```

while client connects to port 80:

```
address="http://servername/ACL.IS.BLService/CustService.svc"
```

I think they should match.

Comment: at some point I did get a window where it says port 80 is being used by other applications and set it to port 8080 but I don remember where that came up. So could you please let me know what can I do to match them ?

Comment: You need to fix you client URL to be `address="http://servername:8080/ACL.IS.BLService/CustService.svc`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a contract mismatch.

Client;

```
contract="BLService.ICustService"
```

Server;

```
contract="ACL.IS.BL_WebServices.ICustService"
```

These need to match

Comment: on the client, its prefixed with the name of the proxy. and on the server its prefixed with the namespace. if I remove the prefixes then I get the error while trying to browse the service in the browser. It says cannot find the Contract in the list of contracts the service implements.